# Symfony update entity without changing field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to update the entity without actually changing any fields.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$test = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyObject')->find($id);

$test->setName("Test");
$em->flush();
```

Works for example if the name was set to something else like "Test2" before. But if it was "Test" before this won't work. So I would like to remove the setName line and just update entity.

I need this cause I have a listener that will only run when MyObject changes.

I tried `$em->refresh($test);` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

well, you want to update an object but anything has changed ... I recommend rethinking the implementation of your listener or you can do this (very ugly) workaround

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$test = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyObject')->find($id);

$originalName = $test->getName();

$test->setName("Whatever");
$em->flush();

$test->setName($originalName)
$em->flush();
```

I would not recommend this solution, you should really implement your listener in the way it trigger every time you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

The events in a listener like you're describing work on the Doctrine UnitOfWork --meaning that they fire and then look at the differences between the previous state of the object and the intended state of the object. I can't think of a way to get Doctrine to persist something that hasn't changed.

In this case, I don't think you want a listener. I think you want a service that you call explicitly.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$test = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyObject')->find($id);

$testService = $this->get('test_service');
$testService->whatMethodYouWantToRunRegardlessOfChanges($test);
$em->flush();
```

And then in TestService:

```
public function whatMethodYouWantToRunRegardlessOfChanges(Test $test) {
   //code that you were running in your listener, called every time
}
```